# Customizing OpenFire for Updating NewsFeed Android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I started learning OpenFire and XMPP, so I could implement it in my android app. My android app displays NewsFeed from a RESTFUL API (rate-limited). I would like to have a server that will download News updates and notify clients, instead of client apps polling the data themselves.

I have setup and played around with the Smack Library. I need help customizing my Webserver (OpenFire) to meet my needs. Any help, advice, guide will be so appreciated. Where do I look to, where do I look for tutorials. Anything. I am willing to learn. Do I really need to build a plugin by myself? I need someone to point me to the right direction? I would be so grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop anything that it's 100% Jabber, of course, you need plugin on server (Openfire in your case) to handle special requests, that means custom IQ messages.

In theory it's possible to "remap" standard behaviour client side, passing by groupchat with a XMPP (smack or babbler) client that sends custom messages wrapped in normal ones but I don't get any point to do that, in short time you'll create a mess. There are many tutorial (not really updated....) on official website and forum. Spark code it's opensource even if uses a really old version of Smack API right now.

---

About Subscription to new users:

You can extend DefaultUserProvider.class and assign it as default "provider.user.className" (you can do it in webinterface or by configuration of Openfire) in place of custom plugin to assign Subscription to new Users. Then your administrative user can send messages (custom IQ for example) to all subriscribers in way like broadcast plugin "official" one

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found some guide on creating plugins. Is it that hard, I was a little scared at first, but now seems, I am out of options. I hope to share my plugin one day, so no one has to suffer like me :(

Comment: yup @MrPk is right, plugin is better way to do such things and creating plugin is easy just follow other plugin check the structure and other way.If i'll get time. I'll make sample plugin for you.

Comment: It's not that hard, it's much harder to configure Eclipse Project ;) plugin.xml it's easy (in Openfire project you'll find tons of plugins), it's a pain to make the jsp if you want to add additional controls like on/off ;) Just get as example a plugin that does something like what you need, so go for a plugin that parses IQ or Packet ;)

Comment: I have followed some online guides and created a plugin. After that, I actually thought it wasn't convenient. Instead I have planned to create a user with administrative priviledges(don't know why is necessary). When a user is created he will grant prescence subscription to this user. This user will be local on the machine the server is on. He will receive requests and send the results as if it was just a normal chat. I am still worrying about this implementation. Any suggestions are still welcome.

Comment: You can extend DefaultUserProvider.class and assign it as default "provider.user.className" (you can do it in webinterface or by configuration of Openfire) in place of custom plugin to assign Subscription to new Users. Then your administrative user can send messages (custom IQ for example) to all subriscribers in way like broadcast plugin "official" one. If that helped please accept the answer :)

Comment: My brother, thanks for your help. Accepting your answer is not a probkem. But it says," you accepted this answer in [date]. You can upvote only when it is edited".

Comment: Do you have anyway I can read more on your recent comment. Seems good to me, but have little idea.

Comment: You last voted on this answer May 27 at 19:14. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.

Comment: @Clinton Yeboah don't worry :) No problem, you are wellcome :)